# Docker image of swipl does not contain jpl

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jhipster, swi-prolog, jpl

I developed a web Application using Jhipster(Spring + Angular). This application utilizes **`Prolog JPL`** interface. While executing it from my machine works, I want to Dockerize this application. Jhipster provides a **`Dockerfile`** that I can build and run `the docker-compose` command.

As I said, I use Java Prolog interface. I tried to modify my `app.yml` to include also **`swipl`** image from Docker Hub.

my **`app.yml`** file

```
...

myapp-swipl:
        extends:
            file: swipl.yml
            service: myapp-swipl

...
```

**`swipl.yml`** file

```
version: '2'
services:
    myapp-swipl:
        image: swipl:7.6.4
        ports: 
            - "8001:8001"
```

I have also included jpl in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jpl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jpl</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But after reading the documentation of the [swipl Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/swipl), it says that jpl is not included in image because Java is not included. Is there any way to make it work like in my machine? Or is there another Docker image that includes **`JPL`**?

If any additional info or code is needed, just ask me to do it.